# Enabling Remote Connection of DBus on CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, dbus

I want to connect to DBUS server on CentOS from another machine on the same network. I just did the following operations for this purpose:

- Edited **/etc/debus-1/session.conf** like below

  ```
  <listen>tcp:host=localhost,bind=*,port=2334,family=ipv4</listen>
  <listen>unix:tmpdir=/tmp</listen>
  <auth>ANONYMOUS</auth>
  <allow_anonymous/>
  ```
- Created **/usr/share/dbus-1/session-control.conf** and added the following configuration

  ```
  <listen>tcp:host=localhost,bind=*,port=2334,family=ipv4</listen>
  <listen>unix:tmpdir=/tmp</listen>
  <auth>ANONYMOUS</auth>
  <allow_anonymous/>
  ```

Then i reboot the machine and try to connect from my client machine, but connection is refused because there is no listening port on server side. Why my dbus configuration is not applied ? How to enable dbus remote connection and which step should i follow ?

Answer (score 0):

DBus should be configured to listen on a network interface which is reachable from the other machine. `localhost` is not reachable from outside instead a network facing interface with a route to other machine and otherway around should be specified.